# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting Accross multiple tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, countif

I have two tables with values in columns A & B.  For both tables A is a numeric value and B is text value. Example below.  I want to highlight cells in Table 2-Column B for which the cell in Table2-column B matches ANY cell in Table1-column B AND the cell Table2-column A is greater than the cell in Table1-Column A for the corresponding match. (So that below Table2 would have cells B2, B4, and B5 would be highlighted).

[image: Table]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula in conditional formatting to do the highlight for the corresponding value in column B table2 and higher value in the same row for column A:

- Select your data in table2 column B
- Conditional Formatting
- New Rule
- Use a formula to determine which cells to Format
- Format values where this formula is True
- write `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3,B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,"<"&A1)>0`
- Format as you like

In this formula:
`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3,B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,"<"&A1)>0`
Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3 is the column B in Table1 change it to correspond to your references
B1 is the first cell of your data in Table2 column B, if your data start in B2 you have to change it to B2

Comment: This shouldn't work, but it does and I can't figure out how it does.  How does the second test in the COUNTIFS() know which amount in Sheet1!A$1:A$3 to compare to without doing some sort of lookup?  Hat's off to you.

Comment: Nm, I got it.  For Row 2 as an example, the COUNTIFS() first checks if B2 = Sheet1!B$1:B$3, and returns the array {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}.  Then it checks if A2 > Sheet1!A$1:A$3, and returns {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}.  There is one position where both tests are TRUE, so COUNTIFS()>0 is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using Conditional Formatting.

You have shown Table 1 and 2 above as if they are on the same sheet,  But both tables seem to start in Column A, which is not possible unless they are on separate sheets.  I'll show solutions for both cases below.

[image]

Starting with both tables on the same sheet, select E1:E5 and choose "Conditional Formatting..." from the Format menu.  Click the plus sign to create a new rule, and select "Classic" from the Style dropdown.  In the other dropdown, choose "Use a formula..." and type or paste this into the formula box:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B$1:B$3,E1)>0,D1>IFERROR(OFFSET(B$1,MATCH(E1,B$1:B$3,0)-1,-1),0))
```

(Note that you can also paste this formula into a cell on the worksheet to test it. It should return FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE when pasted into rows 1 - 5 respectively).

Here's how this works:  COUNTIF()... > 0 returns TRUE if the value in Column E occurs in B1:B3.  MATCH() finds the position of the the value in Column E in the range B1:B3, and OFFFSET() finds the corresponding value in Column A, and IFERROR() gets rid of #N/A values. If D1 is greater than the number from Column A, this part of the formula returns TRUE, and the AND() returns TRUE if both parts are true: The value in Column E has to be in B1:B3 AND The value in column D has to be greater than the value in Column A corresponding to the value in Column B that is the same as the value in Column E.

Here, this results in E2 and E4 being highlighted.

Now if Table 2 is on a different Sheet, we have to use the INDIRECT() function along with the Sheet/cell references in quotes, like this:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B$1:B$3"),B1)>0,A1>IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!B$1"),MATCH(B1,INDIRECT("Sheet1!B$1:B$3"),0)-1,-1),0))
```

Edit:  Maybe this depends on the version of Excel (I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac) but it turns out the INDIRECT() references aren't necessary:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(Sheet22!B$1:B$3,B1)>0,A1>IFERROR(OFFSET(Sheet22!B$1,MATCH(B1,Sheet22!B$1:B$3,0)-1,-1),0))
```

This gives the correct formatting for Table 2, located in Columns A & B on another sheet, as shown below:

[image]